# Define text color for all tikz nodes of a particular type

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I want a particular node type in tikz to have a specific text color. Currently, I have defined a macro for text color. But I need to keep using that macro at every node.

Is not there a better solution? So, just like defining backgrond color for a node, we can also define text color in `\tikzstyle` statement?

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}                                                                                                         
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\newcommand{\whttxt}[1]{\textbf{\textcolor{LemonChiffon}{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

% Define block styles
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=black, text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1in]
  \node [block] (nodea) {\whttxt{Node A}};
  \node [block, below of=nodea] (nodeb) {\whttxt{Node B}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `text=LemonChiffon` option to specify the text color along with the `font=` option to apply `\bfseries`.  Below, I have replaced the `\whttxt` macro with the `whttxt` option to apply these two:

[image]

### Notes:

- You should use `\tikzset` instead of `\tikzstyle` as per [Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52372/should-tikzset-or-tikzstyle-be-used-to-define-tikz-styles).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}                                                                                                         
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
%\newcommand{\whttxt}[1]{\textbf{\textcolor{LemonChiffon}{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

% Define block styles
%\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=black, text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
\tikzset{block/.style={rectangle, draw, fill=black, text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em}}
\tikzset{whttxt/.style={text=LemonChiffon, font=\bfseries}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1in]
  \node [block, whttxt] (nodea) {Node A};
  \node [block, below of=nodea, whttxt] (nodeb) {Node B};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The last `font=\bfseries` option seems redundant...

Comment: @PaulGaborit: Thanks for pointing that out. It was left over from before I defined the `whttxt` style. Have fixed it now.